# How do I properly specify my starting activity in the android manifest?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-manifest

This is my android manifest and for some reason my MainActivity does not start first. The activity that starts first whenever I run the application is RegisterActivity. Can anyone help me figure out why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.indigohate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.indigohate.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.indigohate.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <service android:name="com.indigohate.GCMIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.indigohate" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.indigohate" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RegisterActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.UserRegister"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.LoginActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RideRequest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ride_request" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.TimePickerFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_time_picker_fragment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.SearchResultsListActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.LoadingScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_loading_screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.LostPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lost_password" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RideOfferActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ride_offer" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.StartRideActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_start_ride" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.StopRideActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_stop_ride" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.CalendarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calendar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.MakeCommentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_make_comment" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.PaymentInformationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_payment_information" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.RideHistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_ride_history" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i think remove the 'android:launchMode="singleTop"' from all activities....it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you kept this attribute in your `RegisterActivity`

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Remove all these launchmodes in all activities. Keep it only in your MainActivity:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.indigohate.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" 
 >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The starting activity contains `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` to ensure that it's a `launcher` activity when an app starts.

Comment: I mean singleTop is used to ensure that it should be always a top activity to be started. Because when an app doesn't exit properly for various reasons, the app sometimes starts from the same activity where it has been stopped abruptly AFAIK. Correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: no its okay .. but at the very first time it must launch the mainactivity

Comment: Would it also be the same if I took out all the singletop attributes?

Comment: @user1357998 Yes. If you remove the singletop even in the main activity it should work. But specifying singletop would force the app to always start from that activity in which you mentioned singletop.